# Regex for exact word with small bracket not working in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$string = 'Wow ABC (R+R) : Weldone boy (My Love)';
$variable = "ABC (R+R)"; // this will be dynamic, could be BC (R+R) so I must use \b as boundary in pattern
$pattern = "/\b$variable\b/i";

echo preg_match($pattern, $string)? 'matched' : 'not matched';
```

This is not matching. Even I have tried with pattern `"/\bABC \(R\+R\)\b/i"` and it is still not matching.

[Here](https://3v4l.org/YLiYq) is the link to my testings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern should escape the plus sign, and the last word boundary should be a whitespace boundary

```
\bABC \(R\+R\)(?!\S)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/meT5A)

Comment: Many thanks, this worked, just adding my answer below so people can read full solution.

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of "**The fourth bird**" answer, here is complete example below:

```
$string = 'wow Brands - Love Joy. (R+R) : Weldone boy (My Love)';
$variable = "Brands - Love Joy. (R+R)";

$pattern = "/\b".preg_quote($variable, "/")."(?!\S)/";
$pattern = "/\b\Q$variable\E(\s|$)/";  // this also works (my solution)

echo preg_match($pattern, $string)? 'matched' : 'not matched';
```

**\Q and \E** are also used to not treat characters in them specially. This don't escape forward slash (/).

**preg_quote** makes your string regex ready (escape special characters), here we can escape forward slash (/) also with a second parameter of preg_quote.